# How to cycle through rails model parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up a method in rails so that if there is a parameter has a nil value, the name of the parameter is returned.

I have a model called Usages(gas,elec,biomass)

I know how to do this in ruby:

```
u = {elec: 100, gas: 200, biomass: nil}
t = %w(gas elec chp)
t.each do |t|
    s=t.to_sym
    if u[s] == nil
        puts "#{t}"
    end
end
```

, which returns "biomass"

Say I had this in Rails:

```
u = Usage.create(elec:100, gas:200)
```

How would I return "biomass"??

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `attributes` hash on ActiveRecord models that is based on the database table linked to the class. Empty fields are mapped with nil values, so you can look them up like this:

```
u.attributes.select {|_,v| v.nil? }.keys
```

Comment: Cheers! Can I ask why you've got the |_,v| in there instead of just |v|? Is the _ the key and "v" the value? If so, does it matter what symbol is used for _?

Comment: Was playing around with it and now see that the _ is indeed referencing the key and the symbol used has no significance :)

Comment: @KevL - right. It's just a pattern used to reduce clutter when there's an unused block parameter. Using `|k,v|` would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to loop through the active record `attributes`?

```
u = Usage.create(elec:100, gas:200)
u.attributes.each do |x|
  if u.public_send(x).nil?
    puts "#{x} is nil"
  end
end
```